# I don't go next Activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

I faced too many problems in this project, I don't intent this data, when it's finished it's going to the `HomeActivity`, not `DoneActivity`.

**Details activity:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,DoneActivity.class);
Bundle dataSend = new Bundle();
dataSend.putInt("SCORE",score);
dataSend.putInt("TOTAL",totalQuestion);
dataSend.putInt("CORRECT",correctAnswer);
intent.putExtras(dataSend);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

**DoneActivity:**

```
Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extra != null){
    int score = extra.getInt("SCORE");
    int totalQuestion = extra.getInt("TOTAL");
    int correctAnswer = extra.getInt("CORRECT");

    txt_score.setText(String.format("SCORE : %d",score));
    txt_get_question.setText(String.format("PASSED : %d / %d",correctAnswer,totalQuestion));
```

How to intent this data?

Here's the error:

[image]

Comment: Can you add the logcat error details here what its saying.

Comment: As the @Sunny said please add your LogCat error.

Comment: Why are you using finish(), what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I think __finish()__ is the problem.

Comment: It seems that there is something in your DoneActivity which causes there is crash and as next available activity in stack is Home activity so it is coming in front. It would be good if you check the log and send it here.

Comment: @ihsan.gaozp `finish()` only stop user to go back last activity after intent complete.

Comment: Thank you. Logcat error is here https://i.pinimg.com/originals/4f/be/0e/4fbe0ef967a93c2472a3c78c8105c0ee.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are initializing both text views

> TextView txt_score= findViewById(R.id.**id_of_txt_score**);
>
> TextView txt_get_question= findViewById(R.id.**id_of_txt_get_question**);

```
 txt_score.setText(String.format("SCORE : %d",score));
 txt_get_question.setText(String.format("PASSED : %d / %d",correctAnswer,totalQuestion));
```

Because you are getting the null pointer exception at **Line no 56**.

Means you view not initialized properly.